# Disable DarkMode on android API level < 29 ( Q )

Tags: android, api, android-studio, disable, darkmode

I put this line into my style.xml to disable dark/night mode on my app:

`<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>`

and of course, it works for Android 10 and higher. But currently, I also want to disable dark mode on the previous android version, but i dont find how...

Answer (score -1):

You Can try adding these line just below onCreate method in each and every activity and see if it works

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Comment: Hello, thx for your help, I've seen this solution before, i tried but it doen't works...

Comment: @MariusAlvernhe did you change your theme from `style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"` to `style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` and see if you have made these changes to both themes (Light and Dark)

Comment: Yeah I tried this solution on an empty application and it doesn't works for API level < 29... All the solutions on internet to disable dark mode only work for API level >= 29...